# Do I have to include the license for a testing framework?

Tags: licensing

A common requirement for licenses is that they must be included with the software. Should licenses for testing frameworks with this clause be included if the test code is not something that is being shipped?

In other words: when a library's license asks to be included, is it only with software that directly uses that library?

Comment: If you don't include the test framework in your delivery, then there is also no reason to include the framework's license.

Comment: What does the testing framework's license say? IDE and development tools usually do not license their tools is a way that requires any notifications in software that uses them, unless portions of that product end up included in the software you deliver.

Comment: @JayElston The exact license is Apache 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Does the license apply to the entire library or just the testing framework? If the former, then I'd argue that removing a part of the library before shipping it doesn't remove your obligation to report your use of that library. If it is the latter (i.e. there is a clear, separate testing component within the library with its own license), then I think you can treat it as a separate library with its own license, which you don't have to follow unless you include that separate library.